# Commerce Rule For Sales Tax On Shipping To One State

Tags: rules, commerce

We want to only apply sales tax on orders shipped to a particular State. I tried to cobble together the following rule from the included 'Price Component' and it seems to apply tax on shipping for -all- orders, regardless of the address component.

Can someone look at this and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
{ "rules_apply_taxes_to_shipping" : {
    "LABEL" : "Apply Taxes to Shipping",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "commerce_order", "commerce_tax", "commerce_shipping" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_shipping_calculate_rate" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "commerce_order_compare_address" : {
          "commerce_order" : [ "commerce-line-item:order" ],
          "address_field" : "commerce_customer_shipping|commerce_customer_address",
          "address_component" : "administrative_area",
          "value" : "WA"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "commerce_tax_calculate_by_type" : {
          "commerce_line_item" : [ "commerce_line_item" ],
          "tax_type_name" : "sales_tax"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the Rules Evaluation Log. Apparently the rule isn't even firing. How do I figure -that- out?

```
    0 ms Reacting on event Calculating the sell price of a product.
    3.479 ms Evaluating conditions of rule Calculate taxes: VAT. [edit]
    3.489 ms AND evaluated to TRUE.
        0 ms Rule Calculate taxes: VAT fires.
        0.138 ms Evaluating the action commerce_tax_calculate_by_type. [edit]
        4.267 ms Rule Calculate taxes: VAT has fired.
    7.837 ms Evaluating conditions of rule Calculate Bundle Product Price. [edit]
    7.845 ms AND evaluated to TRUE.
        0 ms Rule Calculate Bundle Product Price fires.
        0.093 ms Evaluating the action commerce_product_bundle_calculate_price. [edit]
        4.688 ms Rule Calculate Bundle Product Price has fired.
    12.594 ms Evaluating conditions of rule Quote Required. [edit]
    12.609 ms AND evaluated to TRUE.
        0 ms Rule Quote Required fires.
        0.012 ms Rule Quote Required has fired.
    12.692 ms Evaluating conditions of rule Calculate taxes: Sales tax. [edit]
    12.699 ms AND evaluated to TRUE.
        0 ms Rule Calculate taxes: Sales tax fires.
        0.111 ms Evaluating the action commerce_tax_calculate_by_type. [edit]
            0 ms Executing rule Calculate Sample Michigan Sales Tax 6%.
            0.169 ms Evaluating conditions of rule Calculate Sample Michigan Sales Tax 6%. [edit]
            2.254 ms The condition commerce_order_compare_address evaluated to TRUE [edit]
            2.263 ms AND evaluated to TRUE.
                0 ms Rule Calculate Sample Michigan Sales Tax 6% fires.
                0.089 ms Evaluating the action commerce_tax_rate_apply. [edit]
                0.571 ms Added the provided variable applied_tax of type commerce_price [edit]
                0.6 ms Rule Calculate Sample Michigan Sales Tax 6% has fired.
            2.905 ms Finished executing of rule Calculate Sample Michigan Sales Tax 6%.
        5.114 ms Rule Calculate taxes: Sales tax has fired.
    17.894 ms Evaluating conditions of rule Unset the price of disabled products in the cart. [edit]
    18.145 ms The condition data_is_empty evaluated to FALSE [edit]
    18.334 ms The condition entity_has_field evaluated to TRUE [edit]
    19.067 ms The condition data_is evaluated to FALSE [edit]
    19.076 ms AND evaluated to FALSE.
    19.102 ms Evaluating conditions of rule Quote Required. [edit]
    19.195 ms The condition data_is_empty evaluated to FALSE [edit]
    19.296 ms The condition entity_has_field evaluated to TRUE [edit]
    19.708 ms The condition data_is evaluated to FALSE [edit]
    19.716 ms AND evaluated to FALSE.
    19.737 ms Finished reacting on event Calculating the sell price of a product.
```

Comment: Looks right to me. Use the Rules log to see if you can tell where it's going wrong.

Comment: I edited question to include the Rules log. It doesn't seem to be evaluating my Rule. How do I troubleshoot that?

Answer (score 0):

No idea why your rule isn't triggering based on the state. From the label, it looks like you're trying to apply taxes to the order total including shipping. So you need two things here you need to configure a state specific tax rule and then you need a shipping rule, and a second shipping rate calculation which applies your tax to your shipping rate. Hope that helps.